Can't read Outlook email with OAuth2
Update: I suspect Microsoft is trying to force me to sign my app with them, and pay $10 a month for the service before they will allow my app to work properly. I'll continue researching, but I am not paying them sh@t.
Are you an expert with OAuth2 and Microsoft? I'd be interested in your thoughts.
I update the code from MailKit that is supposed to use Outlook OAuth2. When I run the test the browser opens, I login all appears to be well and it says "Authentication complete. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab."
But the very last exception fires saying authorization failed. I have tried both imap servers, same results. I'm sure I need to use localhost because I'm working on a desktop app. I changed the port because 80 is not available. I have updated Azure to use the same port I use.
I had to add .GetAwaiter().GetResult() because otherwise the calls hang.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MailKit;
using MimeKit;
using MailKit.Net.Imap;
using MailKit.Search;
using System.Text.Json;
using MailKit.Security;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;

internal class Outlook
{
    const string ExchangeAccount = "my.name@outlook.com";

    public static bool Test()
    {
        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
         // client.Connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

            if (client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("OAUTHBEARER") || client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("XOAUTH2"))
                AuthenticateAsync(client).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            client.Disconnect(true);
            return true;
        }
    }

    static async Task AuthenticateAsync(ImapClient client)
    {
        var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "9999993b-9999-9994-9c95-999f999999b4",
            TenantId = "c999660c-999e-9996-9994-999599999930",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:64722",
        };

        var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
            .Build();

        var scopes = new string[] {
            "email",
            "offline_access",
            "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All", // Only needed for IMAP
        };

        AuthenticationResult? result;

        try
        {
            // check the cache for an auth token.
            result = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, ExchangeAccount).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            // If that fails, then try getting an auth token interactively.
            result = publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithLoginHint(ExchangeAccount).ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        SaslMechanism oauth2;

        if (client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("OAUTHBEARER"))
            oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuthBearer(result.Account.Username, result.AccessToken);
        else
            oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(result.Account.Username, result.AccessToken);

        try
        {
            var challenge = oauth2.Challenge;
            client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // exception Authorization failed 
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}


You should use await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2); - that would be better practice.
